# Unable to start MSBuild language server (see the output window for details) Error on VSCode

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with VSCode. When I start my asp.net core project, it throws this error. I reinstall extension but still same.
I can run, debug etc. my project, everything working good but I am getting this error constantly.

How can I fix it?

Here is my dotnet --info response on working directory:

> .NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   5.0.402  Commit:
> e9d3381880
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Mac OS X  OS Version:  11.0  OS
> Platform: Darwin  RID:         osx-x64  Base Path:
> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.402/
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 5.0.11   Commit:  f431858f8b
>
> .NET SDKs installed:
> 3.1.409 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
> 3.1.414 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
> 5.0.203 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
> 5.0.402 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
>
> .NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15
> [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20
> [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6
> [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.11
> [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30
> [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.15
> [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.20
> [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6
> [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.11
> [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

I checked VSCode output and it said, .net runtime 6.0.1 should be installed. I installed it and problem has solved now.

Comment: Did you see the VSCode's output window for details? What's written in it?

Comment: Thank you for information. I checked my output and it said I should install .dotnet runtime 6.0.1. I did it and error is gone now.

Comment: @DoganCignakli we generally do not add [solved] or similar words to the title.